# include w_thumbnail_src in function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, thumbnails

I got a function that automaticly creates a custom field in the post. I have this located in my functions.php.

`Image` is the name of the custom field and `HERE` is the value. How can I put the function `w_thumbnail_src` as the variable?

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'mk_set_default_custom_fields');
    function mk_set_default_custom_fields($post_id)

    {
        if ( $_GET['post_type'] != 'post' ) {
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image','HERE', true);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and let me add that `w_thumbnail_src` is a function in the same file that looks like this

```
function w_thumbnail_src() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'emphasis');
       echo $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking?  Is `add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image',w_thumbnail_src(), true);` what you mean?

Comment: Thats the idea, but I have tried it and it doesnt work. It just returns a empty value-field. I need the thumbnail url to appear there

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change:
`add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image','HERE', true);`
to:
`add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image', w_thumbnail_src(), true);`

And also fix the w_thumbnail_src() function by changing it to the following:

```
function w_thumbnail_src() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'emphasis');
        return $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    } else {
        return '';  // or a default thumbnail url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try but it didnt work, but I've posted the answer with yuor helt. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that adds the thumbnail url to a custom field named Image.

```
function w_thumbnail_src() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'emphasis');
        return $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    } else {
        return '';  // or a default thumbnail url
    }
}


add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 'w_thumbnail_src');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_id) {
global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image', w_thumbnail_src(), true);
}
}
```